# How to convert RGB to Intensity in Python 2.7 using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Here i have one RGB image where i need want extract plane of intensity.
I have tried HSL, in this i took L Luminosity but its not similar with Intensity, and tried RGB2GRAY but this also little bit similar but not actual.
so is there any special code to get intensity of the image? or is there any calculation of Intensity?

Comment: Would the CIEL coordinate be more appropriate? The colormath https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colormath/ library could be of some help to make tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `BGR2GRAY`(and so on - `BGR2HSL` etc) instead of `RGB2GRAY` - OpenCV usually use BGR channel order, not RGB.

Answer (score -1):

The default format of RGB in OpenCV is BGR. So, you can get the intensity of your image using OpenCV like below:

```
intensity_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
```

`intensity_image[:,:,2]` is the value image of your original image

Hope this helps.

Comment: Value is different from Intensity plane